# n executions of a periodic goroutine

Tags: go, concurrency, async-await, timer, scheduled-tasks

I'm new to Go and have a use-case for periodically executing an async work-function.  I want the interval between work-function executions to be constant (not the time between one finishing and the next starting).  I also want this work-function to be executed some number of times.  This translates to "run work N times, once per M ms".

This is what I have.  I've tried to write `schedule` to be generic for any work-function.  I've also written it so that the first time `work` is executed is at time 0 (as opposed to waiting for the first tick).

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func work() {
    fmt.Printf("work %s\n", time.Now())
}

func schedule(duration time.Duration, max int, work func()) {
    ticker := time.NewTicker(duration)
    defer ticker.Stop()
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    var i = 0
    for {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func() {
            defer wg.Done()
            work()
        }()
        i++
        if i >= max {
            wg.Wait()
            return
        }
        <-ticker.C
    }
}

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("main begin %s\n", time.Now())
    schedule(1*time.Second, 3, work)
    fmt.Printf("main end %s\n", time.Now())
}
```

Any advice for simplifying and making this code more idiomatic is welcome :)